# How can I migrate users?

Tags: users, migrations

I need to rebuild my website, actually built with Drupal 7, and install Drupal 8.

I have some modules that don't exist in Drupal 8. So, I decided to install Drupal 8 and rebuild the website from scratch.

I have more than 100 users already subscribed on the website and I need to import them in Drupal 8.

Is there a way to export them and import them in Drupal 8?

Comment: TL;DR: Migration. Multiple ways actually. One simple option would be to write a script which Exports the nodes as a CSV (or say any other format) and then another script which imports these users in your Drupal 8 site. If you can be specific about the problem you are having during iimport then it would be helpful.

Comment: Use the migrate and migrate_plus module. There are multiple examples online.